# Write Dollar sign in sed command pattern inside makefile

Tags: sed, makefile, pattern-matching

I have a makefile that contains this command:

```
sed '/^$/d'
```

when I ran it I got:

```
sed '/^d'
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated address regex
```

looks like it interprets the dollar sign, how can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 7):

You have to double all dollar signs in a recipe, otherwise make treats them as introducing a make variable:

```
sed '/^$$/d'
```

If you search for "dollar sign makefile" or similar you'll find tens if not hundreds of answers to virtually this exact question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$$`, it becomes `$`. See [Special Characters in a Makefile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/956d3677%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Makefile:
`sed '/^$$/d'`

```
learts@Fastidio:~/tmp$ make
sed '/^$/d'
```